# ExpressionEngine: Multi-Site Manager & Separate Control Panels, Limiting Control Panel Features

Tags: expressionengine

1. I’m testing MSM. Is it possible to provide the individual sites its own Control Panel access from their domain? If EE is installed on domain1.com and manages domain2.com, I want domain2.com to have its own Control Panel (meaning, users don’t need to go to domain1.com to manage domain2.com).
2. Is there a way to limit what a user can access in Control Panel? For example, perhaps I don’t want users adding channels or touching the templates. Is there a way to restrict?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. It's not documented in detail, but it is [outlined in the user guide here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html#multiple-site-manager).
2. Yes, access restrictions are set per member group. You can choose a variety of access privileges, including whether they can administer channels, templates and even specific channel assignments for entry management. If you need to further refine the control panel menus further, again on a per member-group level, I highly recommend you check out [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin), which is MSM compatible.